# Finding least loaded live agent using a single T-SQL statement

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have several agents and one database table (`BackgroundJobWork`) recording the work load of every agent. This table would contain an entry per every work item.

When I want to assign a new work item I first check this table and pick up an agent with the least amount of work items already assigned to it.

When an agent is through with a work item, it changes its status to something other than assigned.

There is a twist. An agent reports its heart beat in another table (`BackgroundJobService`). If an agent fails to report it in timely fashion, its status in that table is set to 'Unresponsive'. The SQL query used to determine which agent is least loaded must examine only "live" agents.

Here is my SQL query to select a **least loaded live** agent:

```
SELECT bjw.AllocatedAgentHostName HostName, bjw.AllocatedAgentServiceName ServiceName,
  SUM(CASE WHEN bjw.WorkStatusTypeId IN (2,3,4) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS InProgress
  FROM BackgroundJobWork bjw, BackgroundJobService bjs
  WHERE bjw.AllocatedAgentHostName = bjs.HostName
        AND bjw.AllocatedAgentServiceName = bjs.ServiceName
        AND bjs.AgentStatusTypeId = 2
  GROUP BY bjw.AllocatedAgentHostName, bjw.AllocatedAgentServiceName
  ORDER BY InProgress
```

Where:

- `BackgroundJobWork.WorkStatusTypeId` of 2, 3 or 4 corresponds to being assigned to the particular agent (denoted by the `HostName` + `ServiceName` pair of fields)
- `BackgroundJobService.AgentStatusTypeId` of 2 corresponds to a live agent

Unfortunately, my query has a bug. What happens if an agent has no entries at all in the `BackgroundJobWork` table? In this case, that agent is omitted from the result produced by my query, even though it is a live agent. That is an ugly bug.

I should probably turn my SQL another way round - instead of looking at the work load table (`BackgroundJobWork`) and then match it against the live status table (`BackgroundJobService`) I should first look at the latter and match against the former and this is because the live status table is guaranteed to have exactly one row per any agent.

But I am not sure and until now did not produce a satisfactory query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I should probably turn my SQL another way round...

Just so. Try left joining BJW against BJS, instead of inner joining BJS against BJW as you are now.

```
SELECT bjs.HostName HostName, bjs.ServiceName ServiceName,
  SUM(CASE WHEN bjw.WorkStatusTypeId IN (2,3,4) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS InProgress
  FROM BackgroundJobService bjs
  LEFT JOIN BackgroundJobWork bjw 
        ON bjw.AllocatedAgentHostName = bjs.HostName
        AND bjw.AllocatedAgentServiceName = bjs.ServiceName
  WHERE bjs.AgentStatusTypeId = 2
  GROUP BY bjs.HostName, bjs.ServiceName
  ORDER BY InProgress
```

As an aside, please consider using INNER JOIN explicitly instead of the outdated comma syntax, for reasons of maintainability.

Comment: I get

    `Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
    Column 'BackgroundJobWork.AllocatedAgentHostName' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`

Comment: I missed changing those to use the BJS fields in the select statement, query updated.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below mentioned query. In this query the part after "Union" is the list of agents which are not there in BackgroundJobWork but in BackGroundJobService, and as they dont have any service running so you can mention any other value there:

```
SELECT bjw.AllocatedAgentHostName HostName, bjw.AllocatedAgentServiceName ServiceName,
SUM(CASE WHEN bjw.WorkStatusTypeId IN (2,3,4) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS InProgress
FROM BackgroundJobService bjs
JOIN BackgroundJobWork bjw 
ON bjw.AllocatedAgentHostName = bjs.HostName
AND bjw.AllocatedAgentServiceName = bjs.ServiceName
WHERE bjs.AgentStatusTypeId = 2
GROUP BY bjs.HostName, bjs.ServiceName
ORDER BY InProgress
UNION
select hostname,'No Service Currently',0 from BackgroundJobService where AgentStatusTypeId = 2
and hostname not in(Select distinct AllocatedAgentHostName from BackgroundJobWork)
```